# How do I use jQuery Mobile to access another page?

Tags: jquery, html

This may seem like a silly question at first, but I can't seem to get jQuery to load another page - when I include a link:

```
<a href="test.html" data-pop >Go to the test page</a>
```

The address (assuming we're coming from index.html) simply acquires a #test.html, which means the end of my address ends up looking like this:

```
html/index.html#test.html
```

My question is, how do I get it load another page? Here's my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"</script>

         <title>Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div data-role="page"> 
             <div data-role="header"></div> 
             <div data-role="content">
                 <p>This is a test</p>
                 <a href="test.html" data-pop >Go to the test page</a> 
             </div> 
             <div data-role="footer"></div> 
         </div> 
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is documented [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/globalconfig.html).  This script included between jquery and jquery mobile worked:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
});
```

Keep in mind that it didn't work for jquery mobile 1.0a1, but it works with 1.0a2.

So whole index.html would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
              $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>

        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header"></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>This is a test</p>
                <a href="test.html" data-pop >Go to the test page</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm just starting in jQuery... where would I put that and how would I style it? Would it be nested in `<script>` tags? It doesn't seem to work at the moment because I still get the `#test` tagged on instead of redirecting. Thanks,

Comment: When I tested it, I put the script in override.js and added <script src="override.js"></script> between current script tags.  Remember to change the jquery mobile version used or it won't work.

Comment: I just got jQuery mobile yesterday, so I should be fine. Thanks!

Comment: So after sticking everything in, your code had no effect whatsoever on the behavior of the link. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added whole index.html that would work - actually set browser url to text.html when you click the link.

Comment: Ah, I found the error. I hadn't put `script type="text/javascript"` so the script wasn't actually running. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, isn't that what you wanted?  If you want to have transitions and load next page dynamically using ajax then the default should work for you (default being strange urls with #some/path).  It won't work on file system though due to same origin policy, you'll have to host your files in apache or something even to test it.

Comment: Well, actually, I just wanted to figure out how to load new pages. I liked the transitions actually. Now I figured it out though. Thanks for all the help,